# How to apply multiple tensorflow functions to the same tensor in parallel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

Let `t` be a Tensorflow tensor of shape `(m, n)`. Let `F` be a list of `p` functions `f_1, f_2, ...` where each function of these takes a tensor and outputs a tensor of the same shape.

I need to compute the tensor `T` of shape `(p, m, n)` such that `T[i]=f_i(t)`.

Notice that this is the inverse setup of the map function where we apply 1 function to a collection of element. Here, we need to apply a collection of functions to 1 element. Additionally, we need to do that in **parallel**.

The naive approach (non-parallel) would be stacking results of these computations generated via a for loop (or a list comprehension).

```py
T = tf.stack([
  f(t) for f in F
])
```

**Tensorflow version: 2.0.0a. Mode: eager**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `r1.13` without eager execution [`tf.parallel_stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parallel_stack) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'll update the question to include version and mode. It's 2.0.0a with eager execution.